# Adding link preview in Angular2

Tags: angular, data-binding

HTML

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="inputBoarder" name="urlName"[(ngModel)]="url" 
placeholder="http://">
<iframe [src]=myUrl></iframe> 
</form>
```

TS

```
private myUrl;
private url= 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMX1mFEmM3E';
constructor(domsanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
this.myUrl = domsanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
 }
```

I want to be able to add a link view as soon as I paste something into the input field. Right now I am able to add the view if I have the link hard coded but it wont reload upon pasting a new one.
[image: Current Output]
[image: Desired output]

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<form>
<input type="text" class="inputBoarder" name="urlName" [ngModel]="url" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event.target.value)"
placeholder="http://">
<iframe [src]=myUrl></iframe> 
</form>
```

TS :

```
private myUrl;
private url= 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMX1mFEmM3E';
constructor(private domsanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.myUrl = domsanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);
}

onChange(url)
{
    this.url = url;
    this.myUrl = this.domsanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.url);    
}
```

Comment: Hey Vivek thanks for the reply but still it doesn't reload the iframe on adding new link. I want to display the link preview when the user adds some link in the input field and change it if user changes the value inside the input field.